# Why my ng-class is not working

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class

I am trying to display spinner when the button is clicked. I had one working plunker and I am trying to implement it little bit of tweak. My [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/TnyIEXjKH49IQZtZb43u?p=preview) is here. I referred this working [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/dZtShpKL1nymZyvLadlh?p=preview)  but no luck. I know m missing something small here.

`ng-class="{true: overlay}[madeCall]"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok both answers point correctly one error, but there is also a fault in logic.

In the plunker you copied it applies a class called `.grey` when it is true but in conjunction with the css, he has e.g: `.grey .overlay`, the result is the desired.

If you want to copy that exact logic you have to add the `.grey` class and also change your css.

e.g:

css:

```
.grey .overlay {
    background-color: #e9e9e9;
    /* display: none; */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

and html:

```
<div ng-controller="mainCtrl" ng-class="{true: 'grey'}[madeCall]">
```

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/6X6A6BxYiAwZ5eMGYVlY?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

It should be:

```
ng-class="{overlay: madeCall}"
```

The syntax for `ng-class` is `{className: Expression}`, if the expression is truthy the class will be applied.

Answer (score 1):

`overlay` should be there in `quotes` otherwise angular will lookup for `overlay` variable in scope.

```
ng-class="{true: 'overlay'}[madeCall]"
```

[**Demo Here**](http://plnkr.co/edit/NhBZ3dNd1EahqM06z7eu?p=preview)

Comment: Pardon me but there is this one critical issue where m stuck in.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35265351/how-to-trigger-some-function-inside-ng-init-when-ui-values-are-dynamic-autocom . Can u plz have a look at it?